# List with name / value pair mapping to object with automapper

Tags: c#, .net-core, automapper

So I have a list of rows with a list of cells, each cell is a string and and object:

```
public List<Row> Rows { get; set; }

public class Row
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<Cell> Cells { get; set; }
}

public class Cell
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public object Value { get; set; }
}
```

Here is an example with content:

```
{
    new Row
    {
        Id = 0,
        Cells = new List<Cell>()
        {
            new Cell { Name = "prop1", Value = "somevalue1" },
            new Cell { Name = "prop2", Value = "somevalue2" },
            new Cell { Name = "prop3", Value = 3 },
            new Cell { Name = "prop4", Value = "24-09-2019 12:27:04" }
        }
    },
    new Row
    {
        Id = 0,
        Cells = new List<Cell>()
        {
            new Cell { Name = "prop1", Value = "somevalue3" },
            new Cell { Name = "prop2", Value = "somevalue4" },
            new Cell { Name = "prop3", Value = 3 },
            new Cell { Name = "prop4", Value = "24-09-2019 12:27:04" }
        }
    }
};
```

I want to map this to an object:

```
public class CustomObj
{
    public string prop1 { get; set; }
    public string prop2 { get; set; }
    public int prop3 { get; set; }
    public DateTime? prop4 { get; set; }
}
```

But how can this be done in Automapper?
I got I working by converting the cell lists to dictionaries and then using automapper, but it then failed on converting of the datetime.
My current implementation is working by using GetProperty(), but whould be nice if I could do the same with automapper.

Comment: http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Dynamic-and-ExpandoObject-Mapping.html

Comment: Lucian, thats how I did it, but it then fails on converting the datetime.

Comment: It works for me. Are you using the latest version? Does `Convert.ToDateTime` work?

Comment: Yes version 9 on .NET Core 3. 
No I can't use ToDateTime, I'm currently using `DateTime.ParseExact(cell.Value.ToString(), "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss", null)`
But also I would like to do it with automapper without first converting to a Dictionary. :-)

Comment: Clearly AM cannot guess in what format your date is represented :)

Comment: Exactly. :) 
That is why I want to know how I can configure it to do it with datetime destinations either with or without first converting to Dictionary, but without conversion would be preferred.

Comment: AM cannot know about `Cell`. All you can do is encapsulate the conversion in a map to dictionary or some kind of dynamic object. I have no better idea.

Comment: Have you tried setting your current culture?             Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-GB");
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("en-GB");

Answer (score -1):

It could be pretty straightforward without Automapper.

```
public static CustomRow ToCustomRow(this row)
{
    var values = row.Cells.ToDictionary(cell => cell.Name);

    int.TryParse(values.GetValueOrDefault("prop3"), out var prop3);
    DateTime.TryParse(values.GetValueOrDefault("prop4"), out var prop4);

    return new CustomRow
    {
        prop1 = values.GetValueOrDefault("prop1"),
        prop2 = values.GetValueOrDefault("prop2"),
        prop3 = prop3,
        prop4 = prop4
}
```

Automapper's purpose is to reduce amount of typing for simple mapping, more complicated cases would be much quicker and comprehensible to write manually.

Comment: Yes, but this is not such a case. What you wrote here, AM can do by default.